# How to change footer Powered by Drupal and its link?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working on Drupal. I want to know how to change that footer text Powered by Drupal and link given to it. I want there "Copyrights 2012 (My site name).All Rights reserved." I can not getting it can any one help me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just go to Structure -> blocks -> Add block

Leave block title blank
block description Custom Footer or any other if you want

and in Block body add following code

```
Copyrights &copy; <a href="http://localhost/drupal-7.12/">TopTableToastMaster</a>.All right reserved.
```

After doing this set default footer's region as none
and add your custom footer.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just create your own block with your own text and replace the drupal one with your own.

To do that, go to the block adminstration area.  Click on Add block.  Add your HTML with your link.  Then put your block in your footer area.

Comment: Thank you very much.It is very easy and usefull.

Comment: Lazy bonus: At least for me, it looks about the same as the built-in one did. I originally wanted to just add my custom text to the built-on one because I was afraid I'd suddenly get 12 point Times New Roman or something at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

go to Structure
then goto blocks
then Add block

Give the block title blank block description Footer or any other

and in Block body add code

Copyrights © Your site name.All right reserved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a themable item, so you can add this to `template.php`:

```
function MYTHEME_system_powered_by() {
  return '<span>' . t('XYZ Powered by <a href="@poweredby">Drupal</a>', array('@poweredby' => 'https://www.drupal.org')) . '</span>';
}
```

Don't forget to rebuild the cache to see the change take effect.