# How to Create and manage Footer Menu in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, menu, footer

I want to add menu at footer in Drupal. 
(e.g. contact us | sitemap | Home )
But the problem is the menu name is get displayed with menu items but I don't want to display it.
Please Help me.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can refer following link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998160/how-to-change-footer-powered-by-drupal-and-its-link> .
This will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure your menu block and put the title as `<none>` to hide the menu title